# RegEx to replace trailing string in specific format

Tags: regex, c#-3.0, text-manipulation

How can I replace these trailing `"N megapixels"` strings with `""` using Regular Expression (`RegEx.Replace`)?

Examples:

> If we enter: "Powershot Yellow 12.1
>   Megapixels", the result would be: "Powershot Yellow"
>
> if we enter: "Powershot Black II 10
>   Megapixels", the result would be: "Powershot Black
>   II"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something simple like...

```
var newStr = Regex.Replace(input, @"\s+[\d\.]+\s*Megapixels", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: you have the input and pattern reversed.  +1 for a good regex, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var newString = Regex.Replace(candidate, @"\d+\.?\d+ Megapixels", "");
```

Comment: you have the input and pattern reversed.

Answer (score 0):

```
var camera = Regex.Replace(input, @"\s+[.\d]+\s+Megapixels", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```